# Javascript properties autoreferencing

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I am trying to autoreference Javascript Object properties this way:

```
let obj = {
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2',
    prop3: [prop1, prop2]
}
```

I choose to do this way for it's better to reference than to do a deep copy of the values. But this returns the following error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: prop1 is not defined`

How can I internally autoreference properties in Javascript object?

I hope I have been clear. Thanks.

[Edit]
For @FarshidZaker asking me, I am going to give a bigger picture of my problem. I have the following:

```
let classes = {
    common: ['active', 'disabled'],
    button: ['primary', common],
    icon: ['loading', common]
}
```

I tried to doing this to avoid repeating:

```
let classes = {
    common: ['active', 'disabled'],
    button: ['primary', 'active', 'disabled'],
    icon: ['loading', 'active', 'disabled']
}
```

If I use normal variables it works, but using object own properties returns the error aforementioned.

Comment: I think you are going in a wrong direction. Please give a bigger picture of the problem you are solving.

Comment: @FarshidZaker, edited for a bigger picture of the problem.

Comment: Jeremy's answer would work fine. Just pay attention that as a result you will have:
    `['primary', common] == ['primary', ['active', 'disabled']]`
I don't know if it's the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, I don't care about this because I flatten everything at the end :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for `.prop3` in the object literal:

```js
'use strict';

let object = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  get prop3() {
    return [this.prop1, this.prop2];
  }
};

console.log(object.prop3); // ["value1", "value2"]
```